# wp-includes/functions.php on line 8

Tags: php, wordpress

I am facing following warning and error on my website:

> Warning: require(/home/content/52/9606252/html/k9grooming/wp-includes/option.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/content/52/9606252/html/k9grooming/wp-includes/functions.php on line 8
>
> Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/home/content/52/9606252/html/k9grooming/wp-includes/option.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5_3/lib/php') in /home/content/52/9606252/html/k9grooming/wp-includes/functions.php on line 8

Line 8 is: `require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/option.php' );`

Comment: so make sure, the referenced file is present, where is it expected.

Comment: Sounds like you are missing some of the core WordPress files.

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree with @doublesharp.

**Note !!** Before doing the below: Try to restore older version of `functions.php` file where an `option.php` may be included, or try commenting out this area in the code. Please create a back-up and do this carefully so you can restore if something breaks. If you have version control implemented this would be easier. If you can't find an older version where `option.php` makes sense, you might have do the below.

**1.)** Deactive all plugins (one by one to see if still experiencing the error). There's a chance it's a faulty plugin. Try to isolate the troublesome plugin -- so you can remove / uninstall completely.

**2.)** If your sure it's not due to too many plugins or a bad one; Try re-installing your theme *(make a back up of what you currently have if you can / didn't already. If you did skip this step).*

**3.)** Re-install theme *(manually via direct FTP connection).*

**4.)** If your still experiencing this error (or a hole as I like to call it). Upgrade to the latest stable version of WP (manually via direct FTP). After you do this, see 1.) 2.) and 3.) again.

**5.)** If this doesn't work; you may need a clean fresh WP install. Delete your WP directory *(see first back-up note on 1.))* Then re-install manually, reconfigure to server (under new fresh DB). Reinstall WP theme again manually.

Answer (score -1):

To fix this issue after 6 years?

You will have to use these changes to files in respectively:

"wp-includes/functions.php":
add before this code at line "7":

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
define( 'ABSPATH', __DIR__ . '/' );
}
if ( ! defined( 'WPINC' ) ) {
define( 'WPINC', __DIR__ . '/wp-includes' );
}
```

! Also with "wp-includes/blocks/index.php" at the line "7"

These codes should just be placed before the problems that are occurred by certainly php-fpm is forgetting the code which is defined in root in the file wp-config.php

Comment: The person's WordPress installation is clearly corrupt. This solution would have them fixing each little issue one by one instead of fixing the main issue at hand.